# Remove impossible if i send an id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I send an id with Ajax. Only he does not remove the selected id from the database?

The Ajax:

```
function delete_category(id) {
$('#category'+id).html('<div class="preloader-retina"></div>');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "categories.php",
    data: "id="+id, 
    cache: false,
    success: function() {
       $('#category'+id).fadeOut(500, function() { $('#category'+id).remove(); });      
    },
    error: function(){      
       $('#category'+id).html('Sorry, Er is een fout op getreden tijdens het verwerken van de gegevens. ');
    }
});
}
```

The Submit:

```
//Check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

foreach ($_POST['id'] as $value) {

    $where = array(
        'category_id' => $value
    );

    $db->where($where);
    $db->delete(config_item('cart', 'table_categories'));

    foreach ($db->query("SELECT category_id FROM " . config_item('cart', 'table_categories') . " WHERE parent_id = '" . $value . "'") as $row) {

        $where = array(
            'category_id' => $row['category_id']
        );

        $db->where($where);
        $db->delete(config_item('cart', 'table_categories'));

    }

}

header("Location: categories.php");
}
```

What am I doing wrong now?

The ID will be received by the Ajax but Id will not be removed

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: What is $db, what is config_item?

Comment: Are you sure that php is receiving the ID correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing an array to php, yet you try to loop through `$_POST['id']`. To send an array you would need to change the following line:

```
data: "id="+id,
```

to

```
data: { 
    id : [id] // send an array of id's under the key 'id'
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure to mark the anser "accepted" (click the checkmark" if this helped you